# Order of map in C++?

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++ and I've been experimenting with the language lately.

I started doing some basic iterations with `map`.

What I found was that the following code:

```
map<string, int> persons = {{"Lily", 14}, {"John", 45}};

for ( const auto &p : persons ) {

    cout << p.first << " is " << p.second << " years old." << endl;
}
```

Always returns:

```
John is 45 years old.
Lily is 14 years old.
```

No matter what the order of persons is (eg if I switched up Lily & John).

Is there any ordering within `map`?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map

Comment: Checking the reference would tell you all you need to know: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map

Comment: The purpose of `map` is to map a key to a value .  If you want a list of pairs that stays in the same order, you could use `vector<pair<string, int>>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes**.

[`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) (as well as `std::set`) is ordered according to its [`Comparator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Compare), which defaults to [`std::less`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less) which calls the overload of `operator <` for the stored keys.

Hence, `std::string`s [are ordered lexicographically](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp).

Comment: Seems clear to me! Thanks for the clarification. As M.M said in the comments, would it be better to use vectors instead? (if I want to have an ordered associative array)

Comment: @MelvinKoopmans `std::vector` won't keep order by itself. You could, however, sort it manually when inserting. A `std::map` is typically faster at inserting towards the middle and retrieving a single element by its key, while a vector is faster at traversing its elements in order. If you end up in need of performance, try and time both.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there is ordering in `map`.

To be specific, an `std::map` orders items by the keys. In this case, you've use `std::string` as the key, so the keys are ordered by comparing strings. Since `J` comes before `L` in the alphabet, it's ordered first in the map as well.

If you prefer, you can supply your own comparison routine (as a function, or preferably, a function object) that specifies a different ordering (but it still has to satisfy a "strict weak ordering" criteria, so (for example) `A<B` and `B<C` implies that `A<C`).